# Алгоритм нахождения разницы двух текстов

Tags: php

По сути, нужен некоторый функционал системы контроля версий.

Работа ведется с текстовыми данными (от 1000 символов до нескольких Мб текста), один текст могут править несколько пользователей. Каждый раз при сохранении изменений, необходимо производить сравнение нового текста с предыдущей версией текста и помечать, что было удалено, что добавлено (достаточно сравнения по целым словам).

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, возможно есть готовые решения, которые можно встроить в сайт на PHP?

---

**Upd:** Нашел вот такое [решение](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php). Буду строить свой сервис на нем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

а это порт на php: https://github.com/yetanotherape/diff-match-patch

Comment: И [еще один вариант](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib). Только JS

Comment: @Deonis функционал на минимальном уровне.

Comment: Спасибо lampa, очень похоже на то, что нужно. Пойду разбираться и тестировать.